# writing new line into text file in matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io, newline

```
function [org_data] = file_manipulation(in_fname, txt_fname, mat_fname)
    org_data = round(load(in_fname));

    fid = fopen(txt_fname,'wt+');
    student_id = '9900';
    txt = [txt_fname ' : ' student_id '\nDate of creation:' datestr(now,'dd/mm/yyyy')]; 
    fprintf(fid,'%s',txt);

end
```

Instead of inserting a newline the file generated is:

```
C:\w2\test1.txt : 9900\nDate of creation:30/05/2012
```

What's the problen with my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sprintf.html) to make those strings:

```
fprintf(fid, sprintf('%s : %s\nDate of creation: %s', txt_fname, student_id, datestr(now,'dd/mm/yyyy')));
```

The way you're doing it now, it treats the backslash as a literal.

Comment: In other words, \n is interpreted by the sprintf family of functions, not at the preprocessor level like other sane languages.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand - even when you don't use variables? (I just edited the answer to replace double quotes with single quotes).

Comment: I'm sorry. This comment is not relevant. I deleted it.

Comment: it does not work with me but I found another solution that say to put \r\n instead of \n and it works with me

Answer (score 1):

Convert the '\n' to double before you insert it to the string:

```
fid = fopen('my_file.txt', 'w');
fwrite(fid, ['First line' double(sprintf('\n')) 'Second line'])
fclose(fid);
```

Thanks to Franck Dernoncourt, Reseach Scientist at Adobe Research.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me to use

```
fwrite(fos, double(sprintf('\n')));
```

Moreover, version after Matlab 2019 version, for saving editor from warning, please use

```
fwrite(fos, newline);
```